# VSTS Workitem Tracking History Architecture

Tags: azure-devops

I need to create a history solution for a custom application and I'am curious how VSTS has resolved this problem in the workitem tracking histroy. I want to create something similar. Does anyone has informations about this architecture or db structure or is there some public documentation about the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Reporting Work Item Revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/reporting%20work%20item%20revisions?view=vsts-rest-4.1) REST API and then analysis for these data.

Besides, if you want to analysis for a certain work item, you can refer the REST API [List Revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/revisions/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1).

And for relate example code, you can refer below links separately:

- [Example project for consuming the VSTS WIT Reporting APIs](https://github.com/sferg-msft/vsts-wit-reporting-example)
- [Work item tracking revisions sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Snippets/Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client/WorkItemTracking/RevisionsSample.cs)